# Setting and checking the id field manually

Tags: javascript, mysql, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on a phonegap application which adds 20 user under a certain super-user . As there are only 20 id's available under one super-user , i have used the auto-increment in id field . Now i am given the following scenario -

1) User1 enters his id as 1

2) User1 then edits his id as 4 as he likes that number

3) User2 registers and the default number comes as 5

4) User2 edits his id as 20

This is where my problem lies , how do i re-check and assign the numbers that have been assigned and then later on edited . As you can see , in the above scenario numbers from 1-4 and from 4-20 would go unused .

Following is the code that i have done till now -

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Application", -1);
var Id = window.localStorage["user_id"];
var Number = '';
db.transaction(function(txaf) {
            db.transaction(function(tx) {
                //store data for local storage
                //var Number = GenerateRandom();
                //var Number;
                tx.executeSql(
                    "SELECT id,number FROM range WHERE superuser_id = '" +
                    SuperuserId + "' ORDER BY id ASC Limit 1 ;", [],
                    function(tx, result) {
                        //if user id found then just update data for that user
                        //alert(result.rows.item(0).id);
                        Number = result.rows.item(0).number;
                        var UpdateId = result.rows.item(0).id;
                        var Data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage[
                            "data"]);
                        Data.number = Number;
                        var DataJson = JSON.stringify(Data);
                        window.localStorage["data"] = DataJson;
                        tx.executeSql(
                            "UPDATE range  SET is_used = '1' WHERE id = '" +
                            UpdateId + "'", '', function(tx,
                                resUpdate) {}, function(e) {
                                //console.log("ERROR at update: " + e.message);
                            });
                    });
            }, function(e) {
                //console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
            });
```

Comment: If a field is auto-incremented, you should not be setting it, but let the database engine set it. IDs/Primary Keys should generally not be set as a part of user input.

Comment: I have removed the auto-increment as of now realizing the problems it would cause .

Comment: But i am still looking for a solution , how would i do it if i go on doing it manually from the user's side .

Answer (score 0):

The id should be unique. This means you need to rejumble the up 20 ids if a user changes his id, thereby changing other users preferred ids. Possible ways out:

1 Don't use autoincrement, do the id bookkeeping yourself. Present the user with a choice of available ids and let them choose from this list.

2 Using a helper table (or use a field in the user table) which maps user preferred id to the autogenerated id.